# Setting the width of a field in sanity studio

Tags: sanity

I'm new to Sanity and currently having a play around building a small project. I have the following schema to create a Heading component my issue is I can't see anything in the docs about setting widths to the fields in the backend / studio area. I was hoping something like `width: "30%:` would work on the object but no joy. I've added a screenshot but basically I want the 3 selects to be 30% width and inline, The the other 2 text fields should span 100%. I tried `columns: 3` but this then obviously makes the text fields 30% / 3 columns also.

[image]

My schema

```
export default {
  name: "heading",
  type: "object",
  title: "Heading",
  fields: [
    {
      name: "seoSize",
      type: "string",
      title: "Seo Size",
      options: {
        list: [
          { title: "Heading 1", value: "h1" },
          { title: "Heading 2", value: "h2" },
          { title: "Heading 3", value: "h3" },
          { title: "Heading 4", value: "h4" },
          { title: "Heading 5", value: "h5" },
          { title: "Heading 6", value: "h6" },
        ],
        defaultValue: "h1",
      },
    },
    {
      name: "fontSize",
      type: "string",
      title: "Font Size",
      options: {
        list: [
          { title: "Heading 1", value: "h1" },
          { title: "Heading 2", value: "h2" },
          { title: "Heading 3", value: "h3" },
          { title: "Heading 4", value: "h4" },
          { title: "Heading 5", value: "h5" },
          { title: "Heading 6", value: "h6" },
        ],
        defaultValue: "h1",
      },
    },
    {
      name: "colour",
      type: "string",
      title: "Colour",
      options: {
        list: [
          { title: "Primary", value: "primary" },
          { title: "Secondary", value: "secondary" },
          { title: "White", value: "white" },
          { title: "Black", value: "black" },
        ],
        defaultValue: "primary",
      },
    },
    {
      name: "heading",
      type: "string",
      title: "Heading",
      required: true,
    },
    {
      name: "subheading",
      type: "string",
      title: "Subheading",
    },
  ],
};
```